# Completely remove mousepointer on Touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen, mouse

i have a touchscreen and it shows the cursor everytime I touch the screen.

can I disable this function? I tried using clutter but this only hides the cursor after 1sec. after touching..

Comment: I'm sorry but your question in its current format is exceptionally vague and seemingly not related to the Pi.

Comment: lol. The touchscreen is for the pi and I want to disable the mouse in raspbian so that I can "click" with touch and the cursor shouldn't show up. So I think it's much related to the Pi :P

Comment: have you considered using a small custom cursor? or an invisible custom cursor - like in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660613/how-do-you-hide-the-mouse-pointer-under-linux-x11)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a program called `unclutter‘

the purpose of this program is to hide the pointer after the mouse has not moved for a certain period of time. Using it, you can make the pointer appear only when the user touches the screen, and disappear right after it. Just set a very fast time and you should be able to make the cursor seem as if it never appeared. I don't have a Pi right now, so this isn't tested, but if you do have any problems I'll attempt to help.

To install it please run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install unclutter
```

And to use it run

```
unclutter -idle 0.001 -root
```

the number is the number of seconds before the pointer disappears. In this case one one thousandth of a second.

Another possible answer would be to run:

```
Startx -nocursor
```

When you start your gui to start it without a cursor. Source reference: https://www.x.org/wiki/AdvancedTopicsFAQ/#index1h2

Comment: I tried to use it, but it only hides the cursor "fast" but on click I can see the cursor. The next thing is I don't want to touch twice to open a link :(

Comment: @JanikH what do you mean by the "next thing", have u tried increasing the time for the first option and/or running the second one?

Comment: @JanikH seeing the cursor can also be a good thing because it will alow you to see where you have clicked and also because it will indicate to you if your touch screen becomes miscalibrated

Comment: @MohammadAli You make a good point, but still it doesn't make any sense to see a mouse pointer on your TOUCHSCREEN. If so, why doesn't tablet or smartphone companies include a pointer for their devices. There is just got a be a way to completely remove it and enable it only when you want to.

Comment: @janihk, have your tried running the gui with the ` nocursor` flag? As shown in the last part of my answer

Comment: @ThN I've seen it a lot on low quality touc screens that often need calibration to indicate to the user that calibration is needed. But you are correct that it isn't commonly seen on devices such as phones and tablets.

Comment: @MohammadAli I have tried running nocursor flag with gui and it did NOTHING.

Comment: @ThN can you try running it like this `startx -- -nocursor`